# printing complete textboxdata in asp.net

Tags: c#

my application if user  wants to print specific data .It prints specific content  but  problem with textboxes with multiline data .Its not printing complete data whatever user  enter  in  textbox.

below is the code

```
<script>

function printDiv(divID) {
            //Get the HTML of div

            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;

            //Get the HTML of whole page

            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><title>Timesheet Details</title></head><body>" +

              divElements + "</body>";

            //Print Page

            window.print();

            //Restore orignal HTML

            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


        }
    </script>

 <div>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"  Text="Print" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/print.jpg"

 OnClientClick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />

       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"

  Text="Print your Timesheet"></asp:Label>

    </div>

     <div id = "printablediv">

       //content
```

empnamelabel  textbox
    startdate     textbox
     enddate       textbox

sun  servicesundaytextbox1  sunvenutextbox2   starttimetextbox  endtimetextbox   totaltimetextbox

mon servicemontextbox1  monvenutextbox2   monstarttimetextbox  monendtimetextbox   montotaltimetextbox

tue tueservicetextbox1  tuevenutextbox2   tuestarttimetextbox  tueendtimetextbox   tuetotaltimetextbox

wed  wedservicetextbox1  wedvenutextbox2   wedstarttimetextbox  wedendtimetextbox   wedtotaltimetextbox

...saturday....

Comment: Is `innerhtml` not returning all of the text? How does the page look before you call `document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;`